# Can Acoustic levitation be used to contain antimatter?

Tags: acoustics, antimatter, levitation

Can Acoustic levitation be used to contain antimatter?

To me, It sounds like an obvious use of the phenomenon, but I didn't find any documentation about anyone trying this on the web, which could indicate that to a professional physicist there's an obvious reason it wouldn't work, otherwise I'm pretty sure someone would have tried it and documented the experiment. Can someone please indicate me what that obvious reason is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Acoustic levitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_levitation) requires a material medium to transmit the sound waves that suspend the object you want suspended.  The object must contact the medium in order to be suspended.  If the object is made of antimatter, it will instantly annihilate upon contact with the material medium that transmits the acoustic waves.  You can't transmit acoustic waves in empty space.

Comment: How could I not think of that...In space, no one can hear you scream! (That was the slogan for the original Alien movie for those who remember ;-)  )...I knew that there was  an obvious answer...

Answer (score 1):

Positrons and antiprotons are contained and manipulated with electromagnetic fields, as they annihilate when close to matter atoms and molecules.

The only neutral atomic  antimatter at the moment is the creation of antiHydrogen in labs. Have a look at the [ALPHA experiment](http://alpha.web.cern.ch/) at CERN.

Acoustic manipulation presupposes bulk matter, the kind that goes with 10^23 molecules per mole. The antiatoms that the ALPHA can hold are  orders of magnitude smaller numbers so their acoustic properties cannot be measured.

In any case, as antimatter, they will annihilate when meeting matter, so cannot be carried by a matter container, let alone fluid etc. Anti hydrogen is  manipulated with magnetic fields in [complicated traps](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168900213012771), and their annihilation is studied when interacting with matter.